# Poisson process on random time interval

Tags: proof-verification, stochastic-processes

Let $N(T) \sim P(\lambda T)$, and $T\sim U[0,1]$. Compute $E(N^\alpha(T)|T=t)), \, E(N(T))$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$.

Clearly that $\{N(T)|T=t\} \sim P(\lambda t)$, hence $E(N^\alpha(T)|T=t)$ is the $\alpha$'s moment of $P(\lambda t)$.

For the second case,

Minor edition after useful comment of @zoli: 
\begin{align}
E(N(T)) &= E\left(E(N(T)|T=t)\right) = \int_{[0,1]}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{k e^{-\lambda t}\lambda^k t^k}{k!}\mathrm{d}t\\
&= \int_{[0,1]}\lambda t\mathrm{d}t =\lambda/2.
\end{align}

Are both of these solutions right? 
Thank you.

Comment: $\int_{[0,1]}\lambda t\mathrm{d}t =\frac12\lambda.$